# User and Admin Logout with Devise and Testing it via RSPEC

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, capybara, rspec2

I am using Devise in a rail app.

I have two models : User and Admin.

Currently, I am able to login as both User and Admin if i visit the User sign in and the admin sign in.

I would like to force a logout of one if the other signs in. What's the best way to do that?

Also, if anyone has a good way to test that in rspec/capybara, please do share!

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would copy over the Devise Controllers and add a before filter like so:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  before_filter :logout_admin, :only => "create"

  def create
    super
  end

  private

  def logout_admin
    # change :admin to :user in the admin's session controller
    # the sign_out is a devise controller helper that forces sign out
    sign_out :admin
  end

end
```

Then for the testing you can access the current user in functional(controller) specs by calling subject.current_user or subject.current_admin, go here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise to make sure to include the test helpers then try something like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Users::SessionsController do
  login_admin

  describe "POST create" do
    it "should logout admin" do
      post :create, {:user => {:email => "tester@email.com", :password => "secret"} }
      subject.current_user.should_not be_nil
      subject.current_admin.should be_nil
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think this will work. How would you test something like this in capybara? are there specific helpers for that as well?

Comment: ahh, good question, as far as i know you can't access current_user from a request spec (and thats probably not best practice either), is there some part of your app's view that is different when a user is logged in vs an admin, or some kind of flash[:notice] to help differentiate?

Comment: so for the above example code, i wouldn't be able to do subject.current_user either then, correct?  I was thinking of using flash[:notice] to notify the user/admin they have been signed out adn the new user/admin has been signed in. I could capture that in capybara.

Comment: no, you can in the functional controller specs, just not in the integration request specs

Comment: and yes the flash[:notice] would be great to test, just run through the normal procedure and then simply say page.should have_content "User has been signed out and Admin has been signed in"

Comment: cool, good luck! Post back if you hit any hickups implementing!